# Unable to access public variable from my main class inside my view page vbhtml

Tags: vb.net, model-view-controller

I'm working with mvc 5 / vb.net. I have a main class with public variables and functions called SQLFUNCTIONS inside the same project.

I declared this inside another public module:

```
    Public mainSQL As New SQLFunctions
```

then I initialized it with connection and everything.

My problem is that I'm trying to use mainSQL now inside the "@code" section of my view like this:

```
    @code
    Dim formules() As Array = mainSQL.sqlERSelect("eb_conditions", "code, libelle, formule", "")
End Code
```

And I'm getting the compilation error: unable to access mainsql because it is public.

I tried to make it public static: no success

can you please help me out?

Thank you

Comment: Why are you trying to do (presumably) a SQL query from the view and not the controller?

Comment: Did you try `Public Shared` or even `Public Property` with constructor definition? I still can't understand why you're using the SQLFunctions instance inside view page instead of controller action.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I have to do it this way because I have to make the call on the click of an html element.
public shared didn't work either